# roswtf communcation error bug in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ros, roswtf, 64bit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am using ros-diamondback on Ubuntu 11.04-64bit.

I am launching the following launch file:

```
<launch>
     <node pkg="tf type="static_transform_publisher" name="blub" args ="0 0 0 0 0 0 blub blub2 100" />
</launch>
```

In another terminal I run **roswtf**

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 2 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/blub] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error:
```

I tried to set ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME by hand, but still the same error. The funny thing is, that there is no error. Everything works as expected. I can listen to the tf topic and receive data.

Can anybody tell me, why **roswtf** thinks that there is an error?

Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10786/roswtf-communcation-error-bug-in-ubuntu-11.04/) by [kluessi](https://answers.ros.org/users/884/kluessi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0